# Verifying variable type

Tags: c++, typeid

I was trying to verify if the entered value was an integer with the type id function. I know that the returned value would be i and not integer. I don't know why any entered value returns false and the programs stops. Any help would be appreciated.
**The program works fine without the while statement**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int number, factorial;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;
    factorial = 1;
    while (typeid(number).name() == "i") {
        for (int i = number; i >= 1; --i){
            factorial *= i;
        }
        cout << factorial;
    }
}
```

Comment: typeid(number).name() returns a c-string and a comparison using == won't work. Use either strcmp function from cstring or convert typeid(number).name() to std::string using string(typeid(number).name())

Comment: Your `number` variable is *always* an `int`, because it's declared as one.  The value stored in the variable is irrelevant.  If the user typed something that can't be parsed as an integer, the value in `number` will be meaningless nonsense, but it's still an `int`.

Comment: Also, the string returned by `name()` is compiler-specific and you can't rely on it always being "i" for type `int`.  The right way to check whether `number` is an `int` is `(typeid(number) == typeid(int))`.

Answer (score 2):

The returned string of the member function `name` of [`std::type_info`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) is implementation defined. It's not guaranteed to be `"i"`. If you want to check the type of an object against another type you should do:

```
typeid(object) == typeid(T)
```

for any `T` type. In your example:

```
typeid(number) == typeid(int)
```

But the above comparison will always return `true` because `number` is declared as `int`. `typeid` is usually helpful to inspect the *dynamic type* of a polymorphic object. In your case `number` is not polymorphic at all. Therefore you don't need it.

What you seem to be worried about is validation of the input. For that you should consider that if `operator>>` of `std::cin` fails the following will happen:

- (until C++11)

  > If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), value is left unmodified and failbit is set.
- (since C++11)

  > If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set. If extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in value, `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` or `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()` is written and failbit flag is set.

Therefore all you need to do is check the fail bit right after requiring it:

```
std::cin >> number;
if (std::cin) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When streams read to an object, they check the format that's being read and parse that format into the object. If the stream cannot correctly parse that data, it sets an error in its error mask. The error mask is used to determine if an I/O operation succeeded or failed. When a stream is put into a boolean context (like in the parameters of an `if()` or `while()` loop), it will return true if its error mask is free of any errors.

If your intention is to only use an integer, then I suggest you adopt the pattern of using the stream itself to check if I/O operations succeeded. For example, this is how it will look in your code:

```
if (std::cin >> number) {
    ...
}
```

The formatted extractor `operator>>()` returns a reference to the stream which will then call its member function `explicit operator bool() const` to access its stream state and return `true` or `false` depending on whether the stream successfully read the contents of the stream into `number`.